# Burninate the Manual tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retagging

The [manual](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manual) tag is currently a duplicate of [manual-transmission](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manual-transmission), however, [manual](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manual) could be easily confused with [service-manual](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/service-manual), so I think we should get rid of [manual](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manual), and replace it with the appropriate "manual"

Comment: If anyone has a more clever title, I'm open :)  These burnation ones are usually fun...

Comment: Burnination complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to agree. Let's do this.

Burnination completed on 16-Jul-2016.